# Filling of 2D array columns according to 1D counter array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, autofill

I'm looking for a numpy solution to fill each column in a 2D array ("a" in the example below) with a number of "1" values as defined in a different 1D counter array ("cnt" in the example below).

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

cnt = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])   # cnt array: how much elements per column are 1
a = np.zeros((5, 4))           # array that must be filled with 1s per column
for i in range(4):             # for each column
    a[:cnt[i], i] = 1          # all elements from top to cnt value are filled

print(a)
```

and gives the desired output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1.] 
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Is there an easier (and faster) way with a numpy routine to do this without having a loop per column?

```
a = np.full((5, 4), 1, cnt)
```

Something like the above would be nice, but is not working.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`  and broadcasting like so:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> cnt = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])   # cnt array: how much elements per column are 1
>>> a = np.zeros((5, 4))           # array that must be filled with 1s per column
>>> 
>>> res = np.where(np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None] < cnt, 1, a)
>>> res
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Or in-place:

```
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None] < cnt] = 1
>>> a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer: even more powerful than what I needed.  The "res" 2D array only changes the cells according to the "cnt" condition to a specific number (1 in this case) and holds the original values of "a" in all the other cells.  This allows multiple uses of 1D "cnt" arrays dynamically adjusting the 2D "res" array.  As a Python beginner, I struggle with the condition comparing a 1D vertical array "np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None]" (5 elements in this case) with a 1D horizontal array "cnt" (4 elements in this case) for reconstructing the desired 2D "res" array. Thanks!

Comment: @wilmert The condition leverages broadcasting. Comparing arrays of shapes 5x1 and 4 results in the following: 1) operand 2 gets promoted to ndim 2 by inserting axes _on the left_ -> 1x4 2) 5x1 and 1x4 both get promoted to 5x4 by repeating along the enlarged axis (only conceptually, no data are actually copied) 3) the actual element-wise comparison is done resulting in a boolean 5x4 array.